# Unknown characters when I write a float on a file

Tags: java, android, io

when I write a float on a file I get a sequence of unknown characters (symbols) but not a float.

```
DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream( new FileOutputStream(filename,true));
        dos.writeLong((long)data);
        dos.writeChars(" ");
        dos.writeFloat((float) mAcceleration[0]);
        dos.writeChars(" ");
        dos.close();
```

Created file with long and floats:

```
 Îîð}  ¾W¿
```

I've also tried with a float and I got unknown characters too. What is wrong?

```
float f=4.3423f;
DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream( new FileOutputStream(file,true));
dos.writeFloat(f);
dos.close();
```

Comment: Looks about right to me for a `DataOutputStream`. What are you expecting to see?

Comment: You're writing binary data, not text.

Comment: It's probably not meant for humans to read it, but another `datainputstream`

Comment: It's printing the binary representation, so you can easily read it into the specific data type back again.

Comment: How can I read it in Matlab for example? I want to see the values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because you cant read binary, it is writing in binary thats why these are `non human-readable` characters

```
DataOutputStream is binary stream
```

Comment: How can I read it in Matlab for example? How can I read in binary in a text viewer?

Answer (score 1):

Use a PrintWriter to write human-readable content to a file.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use DataInputStream readFloat() and readhChars() to read the data, if you cat the file, it will dump the contents in binary format.